# How to group events into an array in a result, while also joining a column showing the most recent event?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a table like so:
EVENTS

| user_id | event_name | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | apple | 00:01 |
| 001 | carrot | 00:03 |
| 002 | apple | 00:01 |
| 003 | apple | 00:06 |
| 003 | carrot | 00:09 |
| 003 | grape | 00:20 |

Where I'd like to group up the data per user_id like so:

| user_id | event_array | most recent event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | apple:'00:01',carrot:'00:03' | carrot |
| 002 | apple:'00:02' | apple |
| 003 | apple:'00:06',carrot:'00:09',grape:'00:20' | grape |

I've experimented with doing something like

```
    SELECT 
        user_id, 
        ARRAYAGG(event_name) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY time DESC)
    FROM EVENTS
    GROUP BY user_id
```

and then joining this on a left join with the most recent event on user_id, but this feels incorrect/slow performance wise. Is there an easier way to group up this into an array and show the most recent event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution using SQL server. you can make use of string_agg function from SQL server to create event_array.

```
select [user_id] ,
       string_agg(concat(event_name , ':' , convert(varchar,time ,24)) , ',') as event , 
       convert(varchar , max(time) , 24) as most_recent_event
from [events]
group by [user_id];
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with [MIN_BY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min_by):

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(event_name) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY time) AS event_array,
    event_array[0] AS most_recent_event
    -- ,MIN_BY(event_name, time) AS most_recent_event
FROM EVENTS
GROUP BY user_id
```